# Ubuntu 18.04. Keyboard layout change does not work correctly

Tags: gnome, keyboard-layout

I'm new to Ubuntu, but I know how to google. I've searched for a solution among similar problems, but couldn't find one for my situation.
I have **Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS** with **Gnome 3.28.2**. I have also **Gnome Tweaks 3.28.1-1** installed and keyboard layout change set to Win+Space. Each time after reboot this combination stops working (the indicator of the input language changes, but, actually, the input language remains the same). I found a workaround: I open tweaks, remove the checkbox (Keyboard&Mouse->Additional Layout Options->Switching to another layout), set it again and the combination starts working. But the problem remains. Please, tell me - what to do, or what logs to read to find a solution. If you need any additional info/logs - just tell me.

The output for `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options`:
`['grp_led:scroll', 'grp:win_space_toggle']`

The output for `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-input-source`:
`['<Super>space']`

Comment: The `Win (or Super) + Space` shortcut, and the shortcut you can set via Tweaks, are two separate methods for handling layout switching. So the problem description is a bit confusing to me. But as a first thing I ask you to edit your question and show us the output from this terminal command: `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options`

Comment: Why do you have that setting in Tweaks at all? The default GNOME shortcut for switching input languages is just `Super+Space`. Why not just settle for that? Probably the two methods for setting the same shortcut conflict.

Comment: I've installed tweaks in the first place, exactly because gnome language switching stopped working at all. And (correct me, if I'm wrong), but according to your recomendation, disabling all layout changing checkboxes in tweaks in case of the conflict should solve the problem. I've tried it. No relief.

Comment: So you have some kind of issue to start with... Can you please edit your question again and add the output of this command: `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-input-source`